# Retain height of 'tr' of table after deleting first column

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I'm working on table currently for which the first column should be deleted dynamically using jQuery. After removal of first column, the tr height is adjusting itself according to the content.

I want the tr height to be same even after removal of first column. Please suggest an answer.

This is the code I'm using to remove first column:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove tr').each(function(){
  $(this).find('td:first-child').remove();
  $(this).find('th:first-child').remove();
    })
})
```

Please see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/zWCz8/1/)

Comment: retrieve height of tr and apply it via .CSS  before removing your cells. tr height will act as min-height since tables shrink/expand to their content.

Answer (score 1):

Add line-height:0px, width and height in your css like following:

```
td,th{
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   line-height:0px;
   height:40px;
   width:100px;
  }
```

See this updated fiddle : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zWCz8/3/) 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Updated the answer , see the demo above.

Comment: Please mark it as your answer if you have solved your problem to help others. Glad to help you.

Comment: no i'm not supposed to change widht and height of table cells. what may be the use if the content gets wrapped that way as in ur demo. bu t thanks u've tried for me

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your tr fixed height in the css or if you want before you delete the col, just inspect the height of your table row and then set the fixed height.

Before you delete:

```
var trHeight = $('tr').height();
```

And then add the new height after you delete the col:

```
$('tr').css('height', trHeight+'px');
```

EDIT: you can replace 'tr' with 'th' or any class you want

Answer (score 0):

I think you should capture your `tr` height before deleting it. So, I tried a bit in your jsFiddle and it worked for me if I changed this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove tr').each(function(){
  $(this).find('td:first-child').remove();
  $(this).find('th:first-child').remove();
    })
})
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tr_height = $('.remove tr').height();
    $('.remove tr').each(function(){
      $(this).find('td:first-child').remove();
      $(this).find('th:first-child').remove();      
    })
    $('td:first-child, th:first-child').css('height', tr_height);
})
```

You can of course choose to capture the height of `td` and `th` in separate js variables.

Comment: this is reflecting only for the first tr

Answer (score 0):

found an answer in some responsive table design

```
var cloned = $('.remove').clone().addClass('cloned');
$('.remove tr').each(function(){
$(this).find('td:first-child').remove();
$(this).find('th:first-child').remove();
})
var tr = $('.remove').find('tr');
var tr_copy = $('.cloned').find('tr');
var heights = [];
tr.each(function (index) {
var self = $(this),
tx = self.find('th, td');
tx.each(function () {
var height = $(this).outerHeight(true);
heights[index] = heights[index] || 0;
if (height > heights[index]) heights[index] = height;
});
});
tr_copy.each(function (index) {                 $(this).height(heights[index]);
});
```

Thanks all